# scala - constrain generic type to specific types

Tags: scala

from time to time, i deal with java that has stuff like the following in it:

```
def printDbl(d:Double) { println("dbl: " + d) }
def printInt(i:Int) { println("int: " + i) }
```

naturally, i'd like to wrap this in some scala, which ends up looking like this:

```
def print[T:Manifest] (t:T) {
  if (manifest[T] <:< manifest[Int]) { printInt(t.asInstanceOf[Int]) ; return }
  if (manifest[T] <:< manifest[Double]) { printDbl(t.asInstanceOf[Double]) ; return }

  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented: " + manifest[T])
}
```

but when i run the following, i get a runtime exception:

```
print(1)
print(2.0)
print("hello")
```

i seem to recall there being a way to catch this at compile time, but i can't seem to google it up. perhaps some clever implied conversions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def printDbl(d:Double) { println("dbl: " + d) }
def printInt(i:Int) { println("int: " + i) }

trait Printer[T] { def print(t:T) }
class PD extends Printer[Double] { def print(d:Double) = printDbl(d) }
class PI extends Printer[Int] { def print(i:Int) = printInt(i) }
implicit val pd = new PD()
implicit val pi = new PI()

def print[T](t:T)(implicit printer:Printer[T]) = printer.print(t)

print(1) // 1
print(2.0) // 2.0
print("hello") // Error:(88, 7) could not find implicit value for parameter printer: A$A336.this.Printer[String]
```

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just take advantage of method overloading and write your Scala wrapper like this?:

```
object Printer {
  def print(d: Double) { printDbl(d) }
  def print(i: Int) { printInt(i) }
}
```

This is very simple and provides the desired behavior:

```
import Printer._
print(1.)          // dbl: 1.0
print(1)           // int: 1
print("hello")     // compile-time type error
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> object SpecType {
     |   trait SpecType[T] {
     |     def is(s: String): Boolean
     |   }
     |   implicit object DoubleType extends SpecType[Double] {
     |     def is(s: String) = s == "Double"
     |   }
     |   implicit object IntType extends SpecType[Int] {
     |     def is(s: String) = s == "Int"
     |   }
     | }
defined module SpecType 


scala> import SpecType._
import SpecType._

scala> def print[T: SpecType](x: T) {
     |   if(implicitly[SpecType[T]].is("Int")) println("Int")
     |   if(implicitly[SpecType[T]].is("Double")) println("Double")
     | }
print: [T](x: T)(implicit evidence$1: SpecType.SpecType[T])Unit

scala> print(1)
Int

scala> print(1.0)
Double

scala> print("")
<console>:21: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of typ
e SpecType.SpecType[String]
              print("")
```

Comment: I guess this code can improved by using Double/Int instead of String and change the layout of the code so that you can do something like: implicitly[SpecType[T]].println(x) See here for example: http://debasishg.blogspot.de/2010/06/scala-implicits-type-classes-here-i.html

Answer (score 0):

this is the best i've come up with

```
class CanPrint[T] (t:T) { def getT = t}
implicit def canPrint(i:Int) = new CanPrint[Int](i)
implicit def canPrint(d:Double) = new CanPrint[Double](d)    

def print[T:Manifest] (t:CanPrint[T]) {
    if (manifest[T] <:< manifest[Int]) { printInt(t.getT.asInstanceOf[Int]) ; return }
    if (manifest[T] <:< manifest[Double]) { printDbl(t.getT.asInstanceOf[Double]) ; return }

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented: " + manifest[T])
}
```

the following does not compile

```
print(1)
print(1.0)
print("hello")
```

and the following does what i expect

```
print(1)
print(1.0)
```

however, this is bad code because i have to import the implicit defs for it to work, and as a consumer of this code all i see is the method signature saying that i have to pass in a CanPrint object, which i can instantiate.

```
print(new CanPrint("hello")) // pwned
```

can i make the constructor private and only accessible to the implicit methods or some such?